# Perl script cannot connect to Oracle from linux shell with error and code

Tags: perl, oracle10g

I need some help in determining the problem with my connection from a perl file to a DB.

The code runs and executes fine when it is run from the web (browser to /file.pl url).

In a shell context (putty), when I run the script "perl /file.pl", I get this error:

```
[date] file.pl: DBI connect('address','username', 'password') failed: 
ERROR OCIEnvNlsCreate (check OR ACLE_HOME and NLS settings etc.) at file.pl line 61
```

Line 61 reads:

```
$dbh = DBI->connect(A, B, C );
```

More details: When another user (with presumably more permissions) runs the file, it works for him (in the shell).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

require 'include.pl';
require 'bencfg.pl';
use lib '/www/modules/'; #rqd
use DBI;
use DBD::Oracle;

print "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n\n";
print "Test Run of connection...\n\n<br>";
print "ORA_HOME: '$ENV{ORACLE_HOME}'\n<br>";  #ORA_HOME: '/opt/oracle/10g/'

#connect to DB
$dbh = DBI->connect(A, B C) || die "Database connection not made: $DBI::errstr";
if($dbh){
   print "OK\n<br>";
   $dbh->disconnect;
}
else{
   print "failed: $DBI::errstr\n";
 }
```

I know the variables of DBI->connect work. Thats not the issue. I believe its permissions but I cant tell how to fix it.

Some additional info:
ORA_HOME: '/opt/oracle/10g'

```
NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS

    PARAMETER   VALUE
    NLS_LANGUAGE    AMERICAN
    NLS_TERRITORY   AMERICA
    NLS_CURRENCY    $
    NLS_ISO_CURRENCY    AMERICA
    NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  .,
    NLS_CALENDAR    GREGORIAN
    NLS_DATE_FORMAT MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS
    NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE   AMERICAN
    NLS_SORT    BINARY
    NLS_TIME_FORMAT HH.MI.SSXFF AM
    NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
    NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT  HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY   $
NLS_COMP    BINARY
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP FALSE
```

Comment: If you do a google search for `OCIEnvNlsCreate` you'll get lots of hits.  Have you examine those solutions yet?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: Yea. The issue here was a poor install/setup. My username was unable to connect and run sql from unix command line. Once that was resolved, the other issues fell in place.

Answer (score 0):

Every time I've had this issue with connecting to 10g, I had to make sure NLS_LANG env var was set:

```
## for utf8 data
$ENV{NLS_LANG} = 'american_america.al32utf8';
## for ios-8859-1 data
$ENV{NLS_LANG} = 'american_america.we8iso8859p1';
```

Plus, set ORA_NLS to path of nls files

```
$ENV{ORA_NLS} = -d "$ENV{ORACLE_HOME}/ocommon/nls/admin/data" ? "$ENV{ORACLE_HOME}/ocommon/nls/admin/data" : 
   -d "$ENV{ORACLE_HOME}/nls/admin/data" ? "$ENV{ORACLE_HOME}/nls/admin/data" : 
   -d "$ENV{ORACLE_HOME}/nls/data" ? "$ENV{ORACLE_HOME}/nls/data"

$ENV{ ORA_NLS32 }     = $ENV{ORACLE_NLS};
```

Re: `More details: ... When another user ... runs the file, it works for him`

Try dumping that user's env settings,

```
env|grep NLS
```

Comment: in the shell my 'env|grep NLS' is NLS_LANG=AMERICAN

Comment: @brbdc  Hmm, I'm not an Oracle expert so I can't exclusively tell you if AMERICAN is a valid setting for NLS_LANG.  Here's a couple urls to read about NLS_LANG  http://orafaq.com/wiki/NLS_LANG      http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_nls_lang.htm      Or else, google "oracle set nls_lang"

Comment: I checked with 4 other usernames in Unix. It worked for 3 of them. We all had the same NLS_LANG variable.  Its got to be some unix permission we aren't aware of. I will post when we figure it out.

Comment: (unrelated) you don't need to `use DBD::Oracle`

Comment: One env var I don't see listed above for you that I've had to set, ORA_NLS.  I've had to set it conditionally based on various versions of Oracle we've used.  Here's an ugly one liner :)  $ENV{ORA_NLS} =
      -d "$ENV{ORACLE_HOME}/ocommon/nls/admin/data" ? "$ENV{ORACLE_HOME}/ocommon/nls/admin/data" :
      -d "$ENV{ORACLE_HOME}/nls/admin/data" ? "$ENV{ORACLE_HOME}/nls/admin/data" :
      -d "$ENV{ORACLE_HOME}/nls/data" ? "$ENV{ORACLE_HOME}/nls/data" :